# Missing badges?

Tags: discussion, badges

I know that the cool kids have been running around talking about "fake internet points" since the mod election.  That probably means that it'd be cool to not need any steeking badges, either, but I'm a nerd and I think badges smell nice.  ;)

I *think* I'm supposed to have Strunk and White and a bronze Cloud badge.  Or maybe I'm misreading the requirements.  That could be the case.

I see other people are getting badges, so it's not that the badge-awarding scheduled job isn't happening.  But I *do* have 100 non-wiki Cloud tag internet points, and I *have* done more than 80 edits and I think most of them were extensive enough (but could be wrong on that), and I don't have Strunk and White or a bronze Cloud tag badge.

Or maybe I've been reading the requirements incorrectly in some way.  Usually, they just magically pop up on my page and I say, "Cool."  ;)

Comment: I see. So this is the *reason* why [suddenly you have many edit history recently](http://serverfault.com/users?tab=Editors&filter=week)? Because it's Cool :D

Comment: Hahaha, yes.  :D

Comment: @masegaloeh Do you realize how incredibly nerdy that sounds?  Oh well, guess I'm not one to talk... anyhow, on the topic of the cool kids and their badges, there's many a stackapps app for tracking badges, or a specific badge.  My personal favorite is [Stinking Badges](http://stackapps.com/questions/2982/stinkingbadges-track-your-progress-towards-long-term-badges), and it's invaluable for the cool, badge-collecting nerd.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With regard to the [cloud](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/cloud) tag badge, you do indeed have 100 points in that tag, but you haven't yet met the second requirement of 20 answers. You got those 100 points from only six answers.

From the [help center](https://serverfault.com/help/badges):

> [image: Tag Badge requirements]

As for Strunk & White, this one is confusing because it has some [hidden restrictions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/84766/189912). For instance, editing only tags doesn't count. I didn't take an *exact* count because I don't have that kind of time today, but I did glance through your history of edits and I see a number of instances where you edited the same post multiple times. That counts only once, though.

The [number calculated for you in /review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/120462/189912) *should* be accurate, barring any bugs (I don't know of any, and only you can see this). I'm sure you will get this one soon.

Comment: Aha!  Yes, you're right, of course about the six answers (instead of 20, haha, yeah, that's a little different).  And I always "misplace" that status bar and have to poke around for it.  It says I'm at 76.  Thanks, Michael!

Comment: Also:  I frequently edit something (mine or someone else's) and spot a typo immediately after hitting save.  So it's fair to only count those re-edits as one, I totally agree.

Comment: Note: the Strunk & White and Copy Editor badges get calculated once a day (last I looked this was still the case), so you will not get them immediately after an edit.

Comment: Thanks, @ChrisS!  I'd noticed that some badges didn't pop up immediately.  It's good to know this is one of them.

Comment: YAY!  http://serverfault.com/help/badges/12/strunk-white?userid=174813

Answer (score 4):

<sub>This post only answers the question about Strunk and White</sub>

PS: If you want to know the progress of some badges (especially editor badges), go to one of review pages then hover on green bar.

Example:

> [image]

---

According this [query from data.stackexchange](http://data.stackexchange.com/serverfault/query/28702/editor-strunk-white-copy-editor), [until Dec 7](http://data.stackexchange.com/help#faq) you just have 56 edits count to badge. Between Dec 7 until now (Dec 10) [you have 25 edits](https://serverfault.com/users/174813/katherine-villyard?tab=activity&sort=revisions&page=1). So 56 + 25 = **81**.

However in 25 last edits, some edits was applied in same posts and the edit was applied to your own post (that doesn't count). So, I think your progress still under 80.

For reference, here the [discussion on meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/442/260672) about which edit that count to editor badges

> What is included
>
> - community-wiki posts
> - tag wikis and excerpts
>
> What is NOT included
>
> - edits to your own posts
> - edits to tags

Comment: Thanks, masegaloeh!  I always "misplace" that status bar and have to poke around for it.  (I know it's in review, but...)

Comment: It's a strange place for it IMO.

Comment: @AndrewSchulman I totally agree;  they're not really items related to the review queue.  The place where I got the > 80 number was the user list, and as Michael Hampton pointed out above, that doesn't really fully address the progress towards the badge.